# Get session id cookie which is created after login to website with jsoup

Tags: java, android, post, jsoup, forms

I'm currently trying to access a website after a successful login but I get an error. I found out that I get no cookies from the `Connection.Response`

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_URL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .timeout(3000)
                    .execute();

            System.out.println(loginForm.cookies());

            Document login = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_URL)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0")
                    .data("email", email)
                    .data("password", password)
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .timeout(3000)
                    .post();
```

The login documents returns the correct website so the login was successful.
I analysed the process with the Google Chrome development tools ([Google Chrome network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyTD0.png)). Thats where I found out that the LOGIN_URL is the same for the `Connection.Response` and the `Document`. I'm also quite sure that the form only wants the email and password and no other hidden inputs (can't give you the link though). I could also find out that there is a cookie (session id) which is created after the login.

`System.out.println(loginForm.cookies());` returns nothing (`{}`) so I can't use `loginForm.cookies()` for further use. It'd be optimal if there was a way to get the cookie from the POST.

Is there a way to get the session id cookie or some other way to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

You can all do in one step by using the `Connection.Method.POST`. So the Response is the Response of the POST

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_URL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .timeout(3000)
                .data("email", email)
                .data("password", password)
                .execute();

        System.out.println(loginForm.cookies());
```